# Investigate Frames in Java?

Tags: java, stack, frame

I am interested in ways to investigate the content of the content of the stack frames in Java (local variables + parameter content). I know the debugger interface is capable of doing it but needs to pause the thread under inspection and I hope for a more elegant way.

Does anyone know some other way not requiring to pause threads but take a snapshot provided by the VM? I know byte code manipulation would also be possible.

Answer (score 0):

[The Serviceability Agent(SA)](http://openjdk.java.net/groups/hotspot/docs/Serviceability.html) in conjunction with JVMTI provides all the necessary information. With this one can access all the data structures of the SUN-JVM doing some magic tricks from inspecting the stack frames, following references, natively inspect (and manipulate) the objects and many more.